# Can we use ansible roles as variable on runtime with --extra-vars?

Tags: linux, ansible, roles

I have a couple of roles that I need to call while provisioning the server with --`extra-vars` option in `ansible-playbook` command. Can someone help me to achieve the same?
Can i use `include-role` option in `main.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it as below:

```
---
 - name: Calling role as per our requirement.
   hosts: localhost
   become: yes
   become_user: root
   roles:
      - "{{ role1 }}"
      - "{{ role2 }}"
```